# Как получить данные о ОЗУ и ЦП в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно получить количество оперативной памяти компьютера, а также сумму оперативной памяти которая уже используется?

Помимо этого ещё процент нагрузки ЦП?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать модуль [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
pip install psutil
```

- [Получение](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c1e4af724e46219f633367dd33e5542925f206b4/psutil_example/memory_info.py) оперативной памяти ([документация](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#memory)):

  ```
  import psutil
  print('System memory:', psutil.virtual_memory())
  print('System swap memory:', psutil.swap_memory())
  ```

  Результат:

  ```
  System memory: svmem(total=34306416640, available=16656289792, percent=51.4, used=17650126848, free=16656289792)
  System swap memory: sswap(total=68666155008, used=38953783296, free=29712371712, percent=56.7, sin=0, sout=0)
  ```

- О ЦП ([документация](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cpu)). [Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c1e4af724e46219f633367dd33e5542925f206b4/psutil_example/cpu_info.py) получения средней нагрузки, нагрузки на каждое ядро и количество ядер:

  ```
  for _ in range(3):
      info = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
      print('CPU percent (interval=1, percpu=False):', info)

  print()
  for _ in range(3):
      info = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=True)
      print('CPU percent (interval=1, percpu=True):', info)

  print()
  print('Logical CPUs:', psutil.cpu_count())
  ```

  Результат:

  ```
  CPU percent (interval=1, percpu=False): 12.9
  CPU percent (interval=1, percpu=False): 13.8
  CPU percent (interval=1, percpu=False): 10.1

  CPU percent (interval=1, percpu=True): [23.5, 4.6, 18.8, 4.7, 9.4, 1.5, 18.8, 7.7, 32.3, 13.6, 21.9, 6.2, 28.1, 21.9, 32.8, 10.9]
  CPU percent (interval=1, percpu=True): [14.1, 1.6, 15.6, 1.6, 4.7, 1.6, 14.1, 4.7, 15.6, 6.2, 17.2, 4.7, 31.2, 12.5, 21.9, 9.2]
  CPU percent (interval=1, percpu=True): [23.1, 12.3, 15.6, 7.8, 15.6, 6.2, 18.8, 10.9, 26.2, 9.4, 23.4, 9.2, 41.5, 18.8, 37.5, 12.3]

  Logical CPUs: 16
  Physical CPUs: 8
  ```